# Can I reference the sheet tab before the active sheet tab without using it's name?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

It it possible to reference a cell in the sheet tab before the active sheet tab?

For instance, my active sheet is 'Sheet 2' but I want to reference 'A1' in 'Sheet 1'. However I don't want to use the name because the name may change and the position may change. For example I arrage 'Sheet 3' in front of 'Sheet 1' or 'Sheet 2'. But the constant is I always want to reference the Sheet in front of the active sheet.

I've tried using Index but the only return I get is the number.

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getIndex(); var num = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[sheet];`(doesn't work)

or

`var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);`(doesn't work)

I know I can write code to reference a cell in another sheet, but I will be creating new sheets and I want them to always reference cells in the sheet tab before it. I don't want to manually change my code after creating the new sheet.

UPDATE:
Thank you! Here is my updated code:

```
function rollOver() {
  // Active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // getting the index of the active sheet
  var index = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getIndex(); 

  //getting all the sheets in the active spreadsheet
  var referenceSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  // Index of active sheet minus 2 to get the sheet before active sheet
  var referenceSheet = referenceSheets[index - 2];

  // Get reference sheet name
  var sheetName = referenceSheet.getSheetName();

  //Get reference sheet cells
  var rollover = referenceSheet.getRange("AW61").getA1Notation();
  var savings = referenceSheet.getRange("BE28").getA1Notation();

  // Insert formulas into new cells
  ss.getRange("AQ59").setFormula(sheetName + "!" + rollover);
  ss.getRange("BE15").setFormula(sheetName + "!" + savings);
  
  //Check variable output
  Logger.log(sheetName);
  Logger.log(rollover);
  Logger.log(savings);
}
```

This code really helps. For my instance I have a button that when it is clicked it creates a new spreadsheet. However, I want to always reference values in the sheet before it.
At first I was just inserting the value of the cell in the referenced sheet, but now inserting the a formula to = that cell it will continuously update the value. Which is huge since I will continue to make new sheets. So even if I change a value of a sheet 5 sheets before it, It will update all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this sample code to always get `reference sheet` before the `active sheet`.

### Sample Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  // getting the index of the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getIndex(); 
  //getting all the sheets in the active spreadsheet
  var referenceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() 
  // Index of active sheet minus 2 to get the sheet before active sheet
  var referenceData = referenceSheet[ss - 2].getRange("A1").getValue() 
  console.log(referenceData)

}
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

[getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.

Comment: This worked perfect !
I added to the code that way the cell in the active sheet would always equal the cell in the referenced sheet.

My Code:  see post edit

Comment: Great! I am glad it helped you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Get the Sheet Before the active sheet**

```
function getSheetBeforeActiveSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ns = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
  const ashn = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  ss.getSheets()[ns.indexOf(ashn)-1].activate();
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)